# Striped Ubuntu box - minimal memory usage

Tags: ubuntu, memory, memory-usage

I am currently building applications with Go, and since I can deploy binaries, there is no need to install servers, databases and whatnot.

My question is: How much can I squeeze Ubuntu so as to have as much memory free for my application? The only things I really need in a server are:

- apt-get (for installing some packages)
- compilers (for C/C++ apps)
- ssh
- Go
- running a executable as a service

Comment: Ever heard of Docker?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works performance-wise. Is Docker a naked linux that runs containers that have all the deps, shell, etc necessary? I am aiming at cheap 1GB ram VPS'.